# I copied a wordpress site, but the database doesnt show!

Tags: database, wordpress, themes

Here is what i did;

I made a wordpress website and i wanted to copy this to another site. 
I made a backup of all the files and the database.
I changed the links to the new site. 
Then i imported the database to the new site. 
I installed wordpress on the new site.

But it seems that the new theme and database isnt showing.
Does anybody know what im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What specifically do you mean by not showing? Not showing in the Wordpress admin menu?

Comment: Yes it isnt showing in the Wordpress admin menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this just recently. I downloaded a plugin which allowed a full export of the wordpress site. I then installed a clean wordpress site on the new site and then imported the old data into the clean site usingthe import function in wordpress. It asked to map old user to new users and that was it - new site up and running. It seems this is built into WordPress 3.x

I think your problem was loading the database with the data and then installing wordpress. The way I described above took just a few minutes and was foolproof.

Comment: Thank you what is the name of the plug in :)?